# Why does each successive unit test in one file tend to take longer to run than the previous ones?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a file containing roughly 150 C# unit tests, and was concerned that it was taking 3.8 mins to run all the tests, with some tests taking over 2 secs, and about half taking over 1 sec.

Obviously some tests intrinsically take longer than others. Nevertheless if I ordered the test results by duration in Test Explorer and watched the run executing, it was clear that as the run progressed the tests were tending to take longer and longer to run.

I then split the tests into four separate test files, and found that it then took 1.5 mins to run the entire set of four files, with no test taking longer than 2 secs and only a handful taking longer than 1 sec.

Can anyone explain why this should be and if there is anything that can be done about it?

I'm using VS2019 with Nunit.

Comment: Check control panel while running.  See if memory is growing.

Comment: By default, NUnit runs tests within the same class in sequence, while it can run tests from different classes in parallel. So probably the CPU load will be higher when it is faster, because your tests use more cores.

Comment: @PMF By default, the NUnit Framework runs all tests and fixtures one at a time. Users can modify that using Attributes. Different assemblies may be run in parallel, at the option of the software that is doing the running - in this case Visual Studio.

Comment: What are the tests doing? Are they isolated from one another or are they using some sort of shared resource? As mentioned above the tests do not run in serial by default . So if you are sharing a resource the later running tests might end up waiting longer for the resource to become available.

Comment: "As mentioned above the tests do not run in serial by default " - I'm pretty sure that actually, yes they do run serially by default as @Charlie said, (https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/technical-notes/usage/Framework-Parallel-Test-Execution.html). No there are no shared resources, nothing clever, just straightforward unit tests.